# What are the respective philosophical perspectives of Saul Lieberman and Jacob Neusner?

Tags: talmud-gemara, historical-figures, conservative-judaism

What are the respective philosophical and methodological perspectives of Saul Lieberman and Jacob Neusner which underly their very different Talmudic interpretation and opus?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, David.  This is a good question, but a good answer would probably fill a book.  Neither was a simple person.

Comment: @YEZ "[_If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much._](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)"

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saul_Lieberman and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Neusner might be a good place to start.